# Zoom at center of image as origin with layout transform

Tags: c#, wpf, rendertransform

I want to zoom image in a canvas control keeping center of canvas as origin .Initially I tried with Render transform it worked well,but scroll bars were not appearing after zoom.I googled about it and found that layout transform should be used for that purpose.My problem is I am getting the scroll bar after zoom now but zoom origin is at top left of canvas,how can I set it to center.

```
 <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Canvas x:Name="grdMain" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">

            <Image  Source="{Binding BmpImageSource,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" x:Name="TargetImage" >
            </Image>



           <!-- <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ScaleFactor}" ScaleY="{Binding ScaleFactor}" />
                </TransformGroup>
            </Canvas.RenderTransform>-->
            <Canvas.LayoutTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ScaleFactor}" ScaleY="{Binding ScaleFactor}" />
                </TransformGroup>
            </Canvas.LayoutTransform>



        </Canvas>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Some suggestions says to set centerX and centerY on layout transform but size of my application is dynamic and I might not fixed center point.

```
 <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ScaleFactor}" ScaleY="{Binding ScaleFactor}"  
         CenterX="250" CenterY="250"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Some suggestions says to set centerX and centerY on layout transform but size of my application is dynamic and I might not fixed center point.

Then you need to calculate the values of the `CenterX` and `CenterY` properties dynamically. You should use these properties to scale around the control's center when using a `LayoutTransform`.

You could for example handle the `Loaded` event of the `Canvas` to apply the `LayoutTransform` programmatically:

```
<Canvas x:Name="grdMain" Loaded="grdMain_Loaded">...
```

---

```
private void grdMain_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Canvas canvas = sender as Canvas;
    ScaleTransform st = new ScaleTransform();
    BindingOperations.SetBinding(st, ScaleTransform.ScaleXProperty, new Binding("ScaleFactor"));
    BindingOperations.SetBinding(st, ScaleTransform.ScaleYProperty, new Binding("ScaleFactor"));
    st.CenterX = canvas.ActualWidth / 2;
    st.CenterY = canvas.ActualHeight / 2;
    canvas.LayoutTransform = st;
}
```